# Spring and HttpClient: The target server failed to respond

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, httpclient, jboss

Добрый день. У меня есть проблема с http client от apache. И так у меня есть 2 сервера которые взаимодействует между собой по REST. Назовем тот, что принимает запросы(имеет АПИ) - Сервер, а тот, что посылает - Клиент. Сервер крутится на 8 томкате и АПИ реализован как @Controller от spring версии 4.2.5. Клиент же крутится в jboss(4.2.3.GA) и основан тоже на spring 3.2.12.  Клиент использует RestTemplate для вызова АПИ на Сервере.
Некоторые методы АПИ на сервере выполняются довольно таки долго, 15-25 секунд. И иногда при выполнении таких методов я получаю следующую ошибку:

```
org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:95)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:62)
```

при этом не смотря на исключение, запрос от Клиента доходит до Сервера выполняется там секунд 15-20 и затем вылетает это исключение. С запросами которые выполняются 1-2 секунды таких ошибок не наблюдалось. ReadTimeout не происходит, все же время выполнения таких методов меньше.

Можете ли вы объяснить почему возникает ошибка и как я могу это исправить?

На всякий случай приведу код Клиента:

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
  RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
  restTemplate.setMessageConverters(ImmutableList.of(messageConverter));
  restTemplate.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);

  HttpHost host = URIUtils.extractHost(new URI("http://127.0.0.1:8080"));
  HttpComponentsDigestRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsDigestRequestFactory(host,new AuthProperties("user", "password", "realm"))
  requestFactory.setConnectTimeout(5000);
  requestFactory.setReadTimeout(30000);
  restTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);
}
```

---

```
class HttpComponentsDigestRequestFactory  extends HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory {    

 public HttpComponentsDigestRequestFactory(@NotNull HttpHost host, @NotNull AuthProperties auth) {
   DefaultHttpClient httpClient = (DefaultHttpClient) getHttpClient();
   httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(new AuthScope(host, auth.getRealm(), "DIGEST"),
        new UsernamePasswordCredentials(auth.getUsername(), auth.getPassword()));
  }

@Override
protected HttpContext createHttpContext(HttpMethod httpMethod, URI uri) {
  AuthCache authCache = new BasicAuthCache();
  DigestScheme digestScheme = new DigestScheme();
  digestScheme.overrideParamter("realm", realm);
  authCache.put(host, digestScheme);
  BasicHttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext();
  context.setAttribute(ClientContext.AUTH_CACHE, authCache);
  return context;
  }
```

---

```
public void post(@NotNull String relativeUrl, @NotNull Object body,     @NotNull Map<String, ?> uriVariables) {
  String url = gateway + relativeUrl;
  restTemplate.postForEntity(url, body, MyError.class, uriVariables);
}

private String json(Object body) {
 return gson.toJson(body);
}
```

Comment: Уверены что устанавливается время таймаута когда вы его сетите? и что нет никаких afterPropertiesSet или чего нибудь в этом духе? очень похоже что значение не выставляется на 30 секунд когда вы его сетите и остается дефолтным, а выпадает время от времени из за данных. т.е. один раз вы превысили таймаут, в другой раз данных поменьше - обработка быстрее - таймаута нет.

Comment: Таймаут по умолчанию 60 секунд, я делаю 30. Даже если установка не проходит, то он остается еще больше. Но уверен, что устанавливается, так как у себя на машине в попытках повторить проблему я выставлял на сервере в методе Thread.sleep(30) и тогда на клиенте сразу вылетал с  ReadTimeout , а если выставлял Thread.sleep(25), то не вылетал.

Не могли бы вы подробнее объяснить из-за чего выпадает? Если я превышаю таймаут то я должен быть ReadTimeout, проверял на нескольких машинах. А в той инсталяции выдает: The target server failed to respond.
Это продакшен,не могу там экспериментировать